# Get the row index and column index of maximum value from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, max

I have 50000 rows and 50000 columns of Pandas DataFrame, row index is from [0...50000] and column index also from [0,....50000], the range value is [0-1]

I want to get the top-n of maximum values which the output is the list of tuple of [row index, column index, and the value itself], for example, the output is `(1, 54, 1.0),(59,0,1.0)....etc`

I used stack `df.stack().nlargest(7)` and I got the result

```
0  21    1.0
   22    1.0
   23    1.0
   24    1.0
   26    1.0
   27    1.0
   28    1.0
dtype: float64
```

I was not able to convert those output to the tuple and it seems it is slow. 
Is there any another way that better than this? or how to convert the stack result to the tuple.

Desire output:

```
 (0,   21,    1.0)
 (0,   22,    1.0)
 (0,   23,    1.0)
 (0,   24,    1.0)
```

Comment: Do you need output Series of tuples or list of tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use if `s` is your series :

```
s.reset_index().apply(tuple,1) 

0    (0.0, 21.0, 1.0)
1    (0.0, 22.0, 1.0)
2    (0.0, 23.0, 1.0)
3    (0.0, 24.0, 1.0)
4    (0.0, 26.0, 1.0)
5    (0.0, 27.0, 1.0)
6    (0.0, 28.0, 1.0)
dtype: object
```

If you want the output to be a list then add `.tolist()`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `Series` to `DataFrame`, then to [`to_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) and last convert to `tuples`:

```
t = [tuple(x) for x in s.reset_index().to_records(index=False)]
print (t)
[(0, 21, 1.0), (0, 22, 1.0), (0, 23, 1.0), 
 (0, 24, 1.0), (0, 26, 1.0), (0, 27, 1.0), (0, 28, 1.0)]
```

Alternative:

```
t1 = s.to_frame().set_index(0, append=True).index.tolist()
```